# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:490)

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create scaled bitmap but on few devices (not all) I get this exception.

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
Bitmap bitmap1= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, 50, 50, true); <--- This line causes null pointer
```

The complete stacktrace is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:490)
    at com.my.app.adapters.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:101)
    at com.my.app.adapters.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:35)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:458)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14143)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4666)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2024)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1845)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now when I look at Bitmap.java line 490, there is no code over there. I am not sure how to solve this problem. Can somebody provide any suggestions, or will be even better if someone can help. Thanks in advance !!

```
     long bufferSize = (long)elements << shift;
        long pixelSize = getByteCount();
                                                 <-- Line 490
        if (bufferSize < pixelSize) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer not large enough for pixels");
        }
```

Comment: Have you verified that `bit` is not null?

Comment: First of all, the BitmapFactory.decodeFile(..) can return a null, if it cant decode an image. You should check this first.

Comment: Regarding that missing code at line 490, you might be deploying on a device with a API version different than your source code

Comment: @dharms bit should not be null, however I am getting the stacktrace is obtained from crash reports. But as Sergio said, decodeFile can return a null, it might be the reason. I didn't pay attention to this earlier.

Comment: @SergioLima Oh, I see decodeFile can return null, in that case this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Documentation:

> public static Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName)

You should pass the path to file as a String object, not an Uri object.

Comment: Thnx, but variable uri is a string, I just named it to uri.

Comment: Then maybe the string you are passing is not valid, try pasting some code.

Comment: Thnx, but I think the problem is as @SergioLima pointed out. decodeFile might return null, also I just checked, I am catching this exception everywhere in my app except this one part and it caused an exception. So most probably that is the reason.